# Как можно скомпилировать целый проект?

Tags: c#, компилятор

Здравствуйте!
Есть такая задумка у меня "Программа для создания программ", может кто нибудь видел программу "Алгоритм 2.0"?
Так вот я хочу написать ПОЧТИ такую же программу только не много доработанную и на другом языке программирования. Так вот вопрос как можно скомпилировать целый проект, не один файл программы "*.cs" а например два таких файла в один "*.exe"?

Comment: посмотрите ответ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477348/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам [сюда](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx).

В частности, для вашего случая подойдёт просто

```
csc /optimize /out:Program.exe src1.cs src2.cs
```

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пытаться что ни будь сделать