# Как программно откомпилировать класс и вызвать его метод?

Tags: c#, компилятор

Есть программа для обработки данных, и несколько раз в день меняется формула расчетов. Т.е. надо каждый раз вносить изменения в код определенного метода и компилировать сборку.
Вносить изменения в код метода можно программно, просто меняя фрагмент текста.
А как после замены формулы из своей программы откомпилировать код, вызвать метод и получить результат?

Answer (score 13):

[c:\temp\code.cs]

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
class Test {
    static public int Run(params int[] values) {
        return values.Sum();  // эта строка часто меняется
    } 
}
```

---

Этот код компилирует code.cs, вызывает метод `Test.Run` и выводит результат.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var code = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\test\code.cs");
            var cps = new CompilerParameters() {
                GenerateInMemory = true,
                GenerateExecutable = false
            };
            cps.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(new[] {
                "System.dll",
                "System.Core.dll" });
            var cp = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            var cr = cp.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cps, code);
            foreach (var err in cr.Errors)
                Console.WriteLine(err);
            if (!cr.Errors.HasErrors) {
                var m = cr.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Test").GetMethod("Run");
                var res = m.Invoke(null, new object[] { new[] { 1, 2, 3 } });
                Console.WriteLine(res);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

[Output]

```
6
```

---

Если значение `var code` указано прямо в `Main`, например:

```
var code = @"
using System;
// ...
";
```

то в `code` надо убрать `\r\n`

```
var cr = cp.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cps, Regex.Replace(code, "[\r\n]", " "));
```

иначе при компиляции будет ошибка: `A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods`.

Answer (score 3):

Добавлю, что при использовании сборок не из GAC нужно помещать скомпилированую сборку в каталог с используемыми DLL

```
static void ДобавитьссылкинаDLLВКаталоге(Type тип, System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection ReferencedAssemblies)
{

    string ИмяФайлаСборки = тип.Assembly.Location;
    string Каталог = Path.GetDirectoryName(ИмяФайлаСборки);

    string ИмяФайла = Path.GetFileName(ИмяФайлаСборки);
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Каталог, "*.dll");
    //   Console.WriteLine("Всего файлов {0}.", files.Length);

    foreach (string f in files)
    {
       if (! String.Equals(f, ИмяФайлаСборки, System.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            if (ReferencedAssemblies.IndexOf(f) == -1)
                ReferencedAssemblies.Add(f);

    }


}
static CompilerResults СкомпилироватьОбертку(string строкаКласса,string ИмяКласса)
{


    bool ЭтоСборкаГак = typeof(T).Assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache;
    string Путь = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(T).Assembly.Location);



    string OutputAssembly = Path.Combine(Путь, ИмяКласса) + ".dll";


    var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    var parameters = new CompilerParameters();

    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.CSharp.dll");
    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof(AutoWrap).Assembly.Location);

    if (!ЭтоСборкаГак)
    {
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof(T).Assembly.Location);
        ДобавитьссылкинаDLLВКаталоге(typeof(T), parameters.ReferencedAssemblies);
    }
    else
    {
        string ИмяСборки = typeof(T).Assembly.ManifestModule.Name;
        if (parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.IndexOf(ИмяСборки) == -1)
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(ИмяСборки);


    }

    if (ЭтоСборкаГак)
        parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
    else
    { //  parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
        parameters.GenerateInMemory = false;
        parameters.OutputAssembly = OutputAssembly;
    }

    parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
    parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = true;

    var res = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, строкаКласса);
    return res;
}
```

Кроме того можно использовать [Scripting-API](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples#exprstrong)

```
String ПолучитьСтрокуДелегата()
{
   string returnStr = @"return (MatchEvaluator)((match) =>
    {
      string x = match.Value;
    // If the first char is lower case...
if (char.IsLower(x[0]))
{
    // Capitalize it.
    return char.ToUpper(x[0]) + x.Substring(1, x.Length - 1);
}
return x;

    });";

    return returnStr;

}

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //   textBoxEval.AppendText(((D)СоздатьДелегат())().ToString());
    string words = "надо заменить все первые буквы в словах на заглавные";
    string pattern = @"\w+";
    // MatchEvaluator evaluator = (MatchEvaluator)ПолучитьДелегат();
    var scr = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.ScriptOptions.Default
        .WithReferences(typeof(MatchEvaluator).Assembly)
        .WithImports("System", "System.Text.RegularExpressions");

    var result = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(ПолучитьСтрокуДелегата(), scr).Result;
    MatchEvaluator evaluator = (MatchEvaluator)result;
    textBoxEval.AppendText(Regex.Replace(words, pattern, evaluator));
}
```

Или более сложный вариант

```
  string ПолучитьСтрокуКласса()
        {
            var res = @" class ClassTest
    {
        string строка;
        public Func<string> ЗаданнаяСтрока;

        public ClassTest(string Строка)
        {
            строка = Строка;
            ЗаданнаяСтрока = () => строка;

        }

       public static Func<string> ПолучитьДелегатОбъекта(string Строка)
        {

            var obj = new ClassTest(Строка);
            return obj.ЗаданнаяСтрока;

        }

        }          
   return new Func<string, Func<string>>(ClassTest.ПолучитьДелегатОбъекта);
            ";

            return res;
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

           var scr = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.ScriptOptions.Default
                                      .WithImports("System");

        var result = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(ПолучитьСтрокуКласса(), scr).Result;
        var делегат = (Func<string, Func<string>>)result;
           textBoxEval.AppendText(делегат("Тестовая строка 2")() + Environment.NewLine);            }
```

Кроме того можно использовать DynamicMethod
[Для рефлектора есть дизассемблер в Reflection.Emit](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=reflectoraddins&title=ReflectionEmitLanguage&referringTitle=Home)