# Проблемы с динамической компиляцией кода

Tags: c#

Стоит задача скомпилировать, выполнить код в реальном времени и сравнить результат выполнения с ожидаемым. Извне передается код метода который нужно выполнить, дополнительно передается отдельно сигнатура метода, параметры метода и ожидаемый результат. 
Например, приходит такой код в виде строки:

```
int M(int x){
    return x*x;
}
```

отдельно приходит сигнатура:

```
int M(int x)
```

и приходят такие значения:
"2" - входной параметр
"4" -выходной

Вот примерный код который у меня получился:

```
        //парсим сигнатуру, достаем название метода, 
        //тип входного параметра и тип выходного 
        var singature = ParseSignature(Signature.Text);
        //считываем ожидаемый результат выполнения
        var resultInString = OutputParametrs.Text;
        //конвертим ожидаемый результат из строки в тип и упаковываем в object
        var resultInObject = ConvertValueToType(resultInString, singature.ResultType);
        //тоже самое делаем с входным параметром (пока входной параметр только 1)
        var parametrsInString = InputParametrs.Text;
        var parametrsInObject = ConvertValueToType(parametrsInString, singature.InputType);

        //формируем текст кода который будет компилироваться (создаеем пустой класс)
        var sourceCode = @"using System; using System.Linq; namespace Testing { class Main { public static ";
        //подставляем метод который будем вызывать
        var methodBody = MethodBody.Text;
        sourceCode += methodBody + "\n}" + "\n}";                                                 

        // настраиваем компиляцию
        var providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"CompilerVersion", "v3.5"}
        };

        var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);
        var pathOutputAssembly = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\"+Guid.NewGuid()+".dll";

        var compilerParams = new CompilerParameters
        {
            OutputAssembly = pathOutputAssembly, 
            GenerateExecutable = false
        };

        compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.Dll");

        // компилим
        var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, sourceCode);

        if (results.Errors.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (CompilerError err in results.Errors)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Ошибка: {0}", err.ErrorText));
            }
            return;
        }
        //подгружаем сборку которую получили 
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(pathOutputAssembly);
        // находим наш класс
        var typeOfMainClass = assembly.GetType("Testing.Main");
        //находим метод который будем вызывать
        var method = typeOfMainClass.GetMethod(singature.MethodName);

        //вызываем метод и сохраняем результат выполнения
        var methodResult = method.Invoke(null, new[] { parametrsInObject });

        //сравниваем результат
        if (resultInObject != ConvertValueToType(methodResult, singature.ResultType))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Результат не совпадает!");
        }
```

Код метода конвертации:

```
    readonly IDictionary<string, Type> _typesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Type>
    {
        {"bool", typeof(bool)},    
        {"char", typeof(char)},

        {"byte", typeof(byte)},
        {"sbyte", typeof(sbyte)},

        {"short", typeof(short)},
        {"int", typeof(int)},
        {"long", typeof(long)},
        {"ushort", typeof(ushort)},
        {"uint", typeof(uint)},
        {"ulong", typeof(ulong)},

        {"float", typeof(float)},
        {"double", typeof(double)},
        {"string", typeof(string)},
        {"object", typeof(object)},
        {"decimal", typeof(decimal)}
    };

    object ConvertValueToType(object value, string type)
    {
        try
        {
            var dataType = _typesDictionary[type];
            return Convert.ChangeType(value, dataType);                
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Значение " + value + " не соответствует типу данных " + type + ".");
            return null;
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Значение " + value + " не соответствует типу данных " + type + ".");
            return null;
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Тип данных " + type + " не существует.");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Есть несколько вопросов:
1) Есть какой-нибудь более простой способ скомпилировать код во время выполнения и "прогнать" его без сохранения DLL ?
2)Как осуществить проверку значений ? Приходится сравнивать 2 object типа, из-за чего я так понимаю сравниваются ссылки а не значения.

Входные и выходные параметры могут быть только примитивными типами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Используйте параметр [`GenerateInMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.generateinmemory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. Об этом пишут в любом учебнике. Есть такой метод - [`Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.object.equals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: GenerateInMemory = true, всеравно сохраняет сборку в файл :( Не совсем понимаю почему Equals сработал а "==" нет, можете пояснить ?

Comment: @SergeyNikolaev _"GenerateInMemory = true, всеравно сохраняет сборку в файл"_  --  GenerateInMemory=true - это не достаточно. также не надо указывать OutputAssembly. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477348)

Comment: все работает спасибо, но есть теперь еще вопрос, каждый раз когда я буду компилировать код, он будет находиться в памяти, как его от туда убрать после того как он уже стал ненужным ?

Comment: @SergeyNikolaev _"буду компилировать код, он будет находиться в памяти, как его от туда убрать"_  -- код копилируется в сборку, загруженная сборка может быть выгружена только вместе с AppDomain. Можно создать отдельный AppDomain, в него загрузить/создать сборку, а когда она будет не нужна, то выгрузить созданный AppDomain вместе со сборкой.

Comment: @Stack _Можно создать отдельный AppDomain, в него загрузить/создать сборку, а когда она будет не нужна, то выгрузить созданный AppDomain вместе со сборкой._ Как можно загрузить сборку из памяти в AppDomain  ? У AppDomain  есть метод Load(byte[] dllAsArray) но непонятно как представить сборку как массив. 
`BinaryFormatter` не подошел :(

Comment: @SergeyNikolaev _"Как можно загрузить сборку из памяти в AppDomain ?"_ -- это не надо. просто создаете AppDomain и в нем выполняете компиляцию сборки.

Comment: @Stack попробовал как вы говорите, создаю AppDomain  `var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TempDomain");` дальше, компилирую сборку в памяти и после выполнения кода выгружаю AppDomain  `AppDomain.Unload(domain);`. Но если смотреть список загруженных сборок: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();` то скомпилированная сборка остается, или я не так понял ?

Comment: @SergeyNikolaev _" компилирую сборку в памяти"_ -- компиляция должна выполняться в домене, который создаете. для  работы с другим доменом надо будет использовать прокси. думаю, лучше создать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @SergeyNikolaev для создания прокси надо наследовать MarshalByRefObject. пример выполнения кода в другом домене приложения - [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3c4f1xde(v=vs.110).aspx). если создадите новый вопрос, то оставьте тут ссылку на него.

Comment: @Stack обсуждение перенес вот в этот вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479842/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0