# Частая динамическая компиляция кода

Tags: c#

Задача такая: есть код  который нужно часто динамический компилировать, и выполнять. Примерно нашел такое решение:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Compiler : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        const string SourceCode = @"using System; using System.Linq; namespace        Testing { class Main { public static void Method(){   Console.WriteLine(""Testing.Main.Method""); } } }";

    public void CompileAndRun()
    {
        var providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"CompilerVersion", "v3.5"}
        };

        var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);

        var compilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
        compilerParams.GenerateExecutable = false;
        compilerParams.GenerateInMemory = true;
        compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.Dll");

        var compileResults = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, SourceCode);
        if (compileResults.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            foreach (CompilerError err in compileResults.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: {0}", err.ErrorText);
            }
            return;
        }

        var assembly = compileResults.CompiledAssembly;
        var typeOfMainClass = assembly.GetType("Testing.Main");
        var method = typeOfMainClass.GetMethod("Method");
        method.Invoke(null, null);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TempDomain");
        Compiler comp = (Compiler)domain.
            CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(Compiler).Assembly.FullName, "ConsoleApplication.Compiler");
        comp.CompileAndRun();

        AppDomain.Unload(domain);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }        
}
```

Т.к. это будет выполняться часто, для экономии памяти создаю отдельный AppDomain, в нем компилирую и выполняю код, по завершению работы выгружаю AppDomain вместе со сборкой в которую был скомпилирован код. Скажите пожалуйста насколько корректно так работать и какие могут быть проблемы использую данный подход (если он вообще верен) ? Нужно ли вызывать сборщик мусора после выгрузки AppDomain ?

Comment: _"насколько корректно так работать"_ -- а иначе никак, если требуется выгружать сборки. они выгружаются только вместе с AppDomain,

Comment: _"это будет выполняться часто"_ -- как часто? AppDomain можно не выгружать каждый раз. а выгружать после нескольких компиляций. и потом, если их какое-то время не было, то выгрузить AppDomain.

Comment: @stack спасибо за совет, хочется услышать ответ по поводу GC.Collect();

Comment: _"по поводу GC.Collect()"_ -- его вызывать не рекомендуют. а если есть какие-то особые требования/обстоятельства, то надо смотреть профайлером что происходит.