# C#: Создать и вызвать анонимную функцию внутри выражения

Tags: c#, функции

Есть ли способ в C# создать и вызвать анонимную функцию внутри выражения?
Без предварительного объявления переменной-делегата.
Что-то вроде этого:

```
int i32 = () => { int x = 5; int y = 6; return( x+y ); }();
```

или

```
int i32 = (() => { int x = 5; int y = 6; return( x+y ); })();
```

или

```
int32 = this.Invoke( () => { int x = 5; int y = 6; return( x+y ); } );
```

**Работающий вариант #1 от @PashaPash и @Pavel Mayorov:**

```
int i32 = ((Func<int>)(() => { int x = 5; int y = 6; return( x+y ); }))();
```

**Работающий вариант #2 от @Stack:**

```
int i32 = new Func<int>(() => { int x = 5; int y = 6; return (x+y); })();
```

**Работающий вариант #3 от @Stack:** (чемпион по краткости, по красоте - для ценителей)

```
int i32; new Action(() => { int x = 5; int y = 6; i32 = x + y; })();
```

Ответ на вопрос **@Stack** "Зачем это надо?:"
Для красоты и компактности, требуется редко, вот пример:

```
int i1 =  5 +  6;
int i2 =  7 +  8;
int i3 =  ((Func<int>)(() => { int x = 45; int y = 6; return( x*2 + y*3 ); }))();
int i4 =  9 + 10;
int i5 = 11 + 20;
int i6 = new Func<int>(() => { int x; if( CheckState( out x ) ) return( x ); else return( -1 ) })();
int i7 = new Func<int>(() => { int x = 0; while( CheckSomthing( x )) x++; return( x ); })();
```

Вот, ещё один пример из реальной жизни:

```
            Style s = new Style();
            s.TargetType    = typeof(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox);
            s.Setters.Add(new Setter(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.FontSizeProperty, 11.0));
            s.Setters.Add(new Setter(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.BackgroundProperty,  ((Func<Brush>)(() => { Brush b = new SolidColorBrush( Color.FromArgb( 255, 200, 200, 200 )); b.Freeze(); return b; }))() ));
            s.Setters.Add(new Setter(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Black));
            s.Setters.Add(new Setter(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily("Arial")));
            s.Setters.Add(new Setter(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold));
```

Comment: я так и не понял почему надо определять делегат и сразу его вызывать. если нужен еще более сложный способ сложения чисел, то можно использовать динамическую генерацию кода. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477348/#477349)

Comment: Непонятно, зачем вам так запутывать свой код. Вот так намного понятнее и читаемее: http://pastebin.com/aw72Ww5s Хотя с теоретической стороны вопрос хороший и интересный.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34516/discussion-on-question-by---c-----).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это можно сделать вот так:

```
var q = ((Func<int>)(() => { int x = 5; int y = 6; return( x+y ); }))()
```

Это - единственный способ.

Comment: Action возвращает void. Замените на Func<int>.

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо

Comment: Действительно, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) **Action<T>** - делегат. Инкапсулирует метод, который принимает один параметр и не возвращает значений.

Answer (score 2):

```
Func<int> i32 = () => { int x = 5; int y = 6; return x + y; };
```

или так

```
var i32 = new Func<int>(() => { int x = 5; int y = 6; return x + y; });
var res = i32();    // = 11
```

если сразу надо получить результат, то так

```
var i32 = new Func<int>(() => { int x = 5; int y = 6; return x + y; })();  // = 11
```

---

**UPDATE**

Для компактности можно записать так

```
int i1 = 5 + 6;
int i2 = 7 + 8;
int i32; new Action(() => { int x = 5; int y = 6; i32 = x + y; })();   

//  i32 = 11
```

---

**UPDATE**

Если определить функцию Set, то можно сократить код

```
void Set(Action a) { a(); }

int i1 = 5 + 6;
int i2 = 7 + 8;
int i32; Set(() => { int x = 5; int y = 6; i32 = x + y; });
```

Comment: Развивая идею с `Set`, тогда уже лучше функцию `T Call<T>(Func<T> f) { return f(); }`.

Comment: @VladD _"лучше функцию T Call<T>(Func<T> f) { return f(); }"_ -- тогда придется писать return x+y; а из-за return получится больше кода.

Comment: Больше кода — да, но код будет семантичнее, и функцию можно будет повторно использовать. Сейчас функция получается привязана к целевой переменной. А ещё, с `Set` `i32`, кажется, не будет definitely assigned (что приведёт к дополнительному коду), а с `Call` — будет.

Comment: Подождите, речь идёт про код, который будет использоваться один единственный раз. И который не несёт семантической нагрузки - вообще никакой. Не нужны тут никакие функции! Ни в коем случае. А за варианты - ещё раз спасибо, такое разнообразие выявило пробелы в моём понимании.

Comment: @АндрейВдовенко: Если он не несёт семантической нагрузки, то его нужно развернуть, и он станет проще. Группировка имеет смысл лишь для подчёркивания семантики.

Comment: @АндрейВдовенко в F# можно записать еще компактнее: `let i32 = let x = 5 in let y = 6 in x + y`

Comment: @АндрейВдовенко: Сравните, например, `int i6 = new Func<int>(() => { int x; if( CheckState( out x ) ) return( x ); else return( -1 ) })();` и `int i6; if( !CheckState( out i6 ) ) i6 = -1;`. Если функцию заинлайнить, будет проще **всегда**.

Comment: @VladD наверное, это уже вопрос личных предпочтений. Хочется иметь возможность окинуть взглядом код и понять основные блоки и связь между ними. На высоком уровне абстракции. Что бы второстепенное не отвлекало. Для этого, в том числе, применяется единообразие оформления. Вот, в примере сверху 7 строк (или 70) - они не отвлекут внимание; что бы понять их суть потребуются беглый взгляд и доли секунды. В общем, это всё _про оформление_, что, повторюсь, является делом личным.

Comment: @VladD: 'int i6; if( !CheckState( out i6 ) ) i6 = -1;' Без комментариев. Однако же, Вы записали это в 1 строчку, и увидели что это хорошо. Признаюсь, кроме решения с анонимной функцией, я увидел что во многих *частных* случаях есть ещё более короткий способ.

Comment: @АндрейВдовенко: Если в функции есть _несколько_ блоков, то возможно он слишком длинная, и у неё слишком сложная семантика. Тогда её надо разбить на семантически более простые части (простое правило: вы должны смочь _назвать_ действие, выполняемое функцией, короткой фразой, 3-4 слова), дать им названия и оформить отдельными функциями. Несемантическое разбиение скорее всего не очень правильно. (Впрочем, мы ушли в оффтопик.)

Comment: @АндрейВдовенко: Я записал в одну строчку, это да. Но если бы это был _мой_ код, я бы определил семантику этого присвоения, и вынес это в именованную функцию. `GetStateOrDefault` или что-то наподобие. (И она бы содержала, конечно, именно то, что у вас в анонимной функции.)

Comment: Ко мнению специалистов, дающих настолько хорошие ответы, стоит прислушаться.Даже, если, пока что, я думаю по-другому.