# Как удобно создавать Immutable Value Object с большим количеством свойств в C#

Tags: c#

Задача в том, чтобы с наименьшим количеством кода определить немутируемый (*immutable*) *ValueObject* с большим количеством свойств.

Использую *NHibernate* как *ORM*, поэтому свойства должны быть `virtual` и `public`/`protected`. Этот объект мэпится к таблице из БД.

Этот объект не должен меняться, но надо, чтобы его можно было создать.

Если свойств не много, то проблем нет, например так:

```
public class ElectricDevice
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; protected set; }
    public virtual bool IsDecommissioned { get; protected set;}

    public ElectricDevice(int id, string name, bool isDecommissioned)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        IsDecommissioned = isDecommissioned;
    }
}
```

Но если свойств становится много, например, 20, то как-то неудобно, долго писать класс (таких классов к тому же должно быть много). Так же не красиво создавать такой объект через конструктор. Есть какие-нибудь идеи? Может быть в C#6 какой-нибудь новый синтаксис?

Comment: Как насчёт паттерна Builder?

Comment: Наподобие `ElectricDevice electricDevice = new ElectricDeviceBuilder() { Id = id, Name = name, OtherProperty = otherValue }.Build();`

Comment: Судя по тому, как вы его используете - вам кодогенерация нужна, а не удобный конструктор.

Comment: @VladD, да, это то самое, что хотел услышать. Можно еще fluent notation использовать для формирования билдера.

Comment: P.S. Можно кодогенерацию сделать и для билдера. Или написать вручную, это будет опять долго, но зато красиво.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужен fluent-интерфейс, у меня получилось вот такое решение, основанное на ответе @Stack:

1. Заводим атрибут, чтобы отмечать классы, к которым нужно строить `Builder`:

   ```
   namespace BuildCodegen
   {
       class CreateBuilderAttribute : Attribute { }
   }
   ```

   Помечаем этим атрибутом наш класс:

   ```
   [CreateBuilder]
   public class ElectricDevice
   {
       public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
       public virtual string Name { get; protected set; }
       public virtual bool IsDecommissioned { get; protected set; }

       public ElectricDevice(int id, string name, bool isDecommissioned)
       {
           Id = id;
           Name = name;
           IsDecommissioned = isDecommissioned;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Заводим в нашем проекте TextTemplate (в [соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484929/10105) расписано, как именно это делается), называем его `Builders.tt`.

   Для доступа к существующему коду используем [`CodeModel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983770.aspx), а не рефлексию, т. к. у рефлексии есть известные проблемы (несвоевременное обновление, блокировка сборок в памяти).

   Итак, помещаем в `Builders.tt` следующий код:

   ```
   <# /* hostspecific = true, т. к. мы используем CodeModel Visual Studio */ #>
   <#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
   <#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
   <#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
   <#@ assembly name="EnvDte" #>
   <#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
   <#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
   <#@ import namespace="System.Collections" #>
   <#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
   <#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
   <#@ output extension=".cs" #>
   <#
   // задаём вручную имя атрибута (как сделать лучше?)
   var attributeFullName = "BuildCodegen.CreateBuilderAttribute";
   var visualStudio = (EnvDTE.DTE)((this.Host as IServiceProvider)
           .GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)));
   var project = (EnvDTE.Project)visualStudio.Solution
           .FindProjectItem(this.Host.TemplateFile).ContainingProject;
   var codeModel = project.CodeModel;
   // получили модель кода:
   var classes = codeModel.CodeElements.Cast<CodeElement>().SelectMany(GetClasses);
   var classesThatNeedBuilder =
       classes.Where(c => c.Attributes.Cast<CodeAttribute>()
                           .Any(attr => attr.FullName == attributeFullName));
   foreach (var ccl in classesThatNeedBuilder)
   {
       var namespaceName = ccl.Namespace.FullName;
       var className = ccl.Name;
       var builderName = className + "Builder";
       var properties = ccl.Children
                           .OfType<CodeProperty>()
                           .Select(p => new PropertyDescriptor(p))
                           .ToList();
       // Каждый builder кладём в то же пространство имён, что и
       // производимый им класс. (Это легко переделать, разумеется.)
       // Также мы предполагаем, что у производимого класса есть
       // конструктор, принимающий все атрибуты, с именами, соответствующими
       // именам свойств, но со строчной буквы (если это не так, нужно
       // поискать конструктор и имена параметров через CodeModel)
   #>

   namespace <#= namespaceName #>
   {
       public class <#= builderName #>
       {
           public <#= className #> Build()
           {
               return new <#= className #>(<#=
                   string.Join(", ", properties.Select(p =>
                           p.LowerName + ": " + p.LowerName))
               #>);
           }
   <#
   foreach (var prop in properties)
   {
       // для каждого из свойств определяем несущее поле и
       // fluent-метод его установки
   #>

           <#= prop.Type #> <#= prop.LowerName #>;

           public <#= builderName #> With<#= prop.UpperName #>(<#=
               prop.Type #> <#= prop.LowerName #>)
           {
               this.<#= prop.LowerName #> = <#= prop.LowerName #>;
               return this;
           }
   <#
   }
   #>
       }
   }

   <#
   }
   #>

   <#+
   // вспомогательный метод: получаем рекурсивно список классов
   // мы смотрим только внутри пространств имён, но не внутри других классов
   // (исключительно из-за лени, ну и нужно для вложенного класса придумать,
   // куда же класть builder)
   IEnumerable<CodeClass> GetClasses(CodeElement elt)
   {
       CodeClass ccl = elt as CodeClass;
       if (ccl != null)
           return new[] { ccl };
       CodeNamespace cns = elt as CodeNamespace;
       if (cns != null)
           return cns.Members.Cast<CodeElement>().SelectMany(GetClasses);
       return Enumerable.Empty<CodeClass>();
   }

   // ну и мелкий класс-обёртка для свойства
   class PropertyDescriptor
   {
       public readonly string Type;
       public readonly string UpperName;
       public readonly string LowerName;

       public PropertyDescriptor(CodeProperty property)
       {
           this.Type = property.Type.AsString;
           var name = property.Name;
           this.UpperName = char.ToUpper(name[0]) + name.Substring(1);
           this.LowerName = char.ToLower(name[0]) + name.Substring(1);
       }
   }
   #>
   ```
3. Получаем такой автоматически сгенерированный класс:

   ```
   namespace BuildCodegen
   {
       public class ElectricDeviceBuilder
       {
           public ElectricDevice Build()
           {
               return new ElectricDevice(id: id, name: name, isDecommissioned: isDecommissioned);
           }

           int id;

           public ElectricDeviceBuilder WithId(int id)
           {
               this.id = id;
               return this;
           }

           string name;

           public ElectricDeviceBuilder WithName(string name)
           {
               this.name = name;
               return this;
           }

           bool isDecommissioned;

           public ElectricDeviceBuilder WithIsDecommissioned(bool isDecommissioned)
           {
               this.isDecommissioned = isDecommissioned;
               return this;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Кстати, сам Entity-класс тоже можно генерировать автоматически.

Answer (score 6):

> если свойств становится много, например, 20, то как-то неудобно, долго писать класс

Если надо определить класс-обертку для таблицы из БД, в котором много свойств, то можно использовать **T4 -- генератор кода** в Visual Studio.
Для этого в Visual Studio надо нажать Ctrl+Shift+A, Ctrl+E, набрать t4, и выбрать Text Template. В созданном файле TextTemplate.tt указать следующий код:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#
var cs = @"Data Source=(localdb)\DB;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True;";
var cn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(cs);
// тут читаем схему базы дынных и создаем коллекцию имен и типов свойств
// ... 
var ps = new [] { 
           new [] { "p1", "int" },
           new [] { "p2", "string" }
           // ... много других элементов
           };
#>
namespace App { 
    public class Wrapper {
        <# foreach(var p in ps) { #>
            public virtual <#= p[1] #> <#= p[0] #> { get; protected set; }
        <# } #>
    }
}
```

При сохранении TextTemplate.tt будет создан TextTemplate.сs

```
 namespace App { 
    public class Wrapper {
        public virtual int p1 { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string p2 { get; protected set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Кстати, круто. Кодогенерация это всегда хорошо.

Comment: [Почитать по T4 кодогенирации можно тут](http://smarly.net/metaprogramming-in-net/techniques-for-generating-code/the-text-template-transformation-toolkit-(t4))

Comment: Спасибо! Это может упростить жизнь, но пользоваться этим классом будет так же сложно как и раньше. То, что я хотел услышать это  `ElectricDevice electricDevice = new ElectricDeviceBuilder() { Id = id, Name = name, OtherProperty = otherValue }.Build();`. Если буду делать кодогенерацию, то знаю где смотреть пример.

Comment: P.S. для такого билдера тоже можно сделать кодогенерацию, кстати.

Comment: @AndreyK.если нужно создавать и компилировать классы в рантайме, то можно использовать CodeDom.Compiler. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477349/196972)

Comment: @Stack: По идее, можно и в compile time через T4. Попробую набросать.

Comment: @Stack: Вроде готово. Доразвил вашу идею.

Comment: @VladD _"Вроде готово"_ -- хорошо. если "объект мэпится к таблице из БД.", то можно и сам класс объекта, и fluent к нему, герерировать в T4.

Comment: @Stack: Так и есть. Заодно будет гарантированное согласование конструкторов :)

Answer (score 2):

На всякий случай, напишу про то как можно избежать прописывание вручную многих параметров в конструктор. Если что, то критикуйте.

Объект:

```
public class RoadDevice
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; protected set; }
    public virtual bool IsDecommissioned { get; protected set;}

    protected RoadDevice()
    {

    }
}
```

Билдер:

```
//Этот объкт immutable и в перспективе достаточно большой, поэтому для него можно сделать билдер для удобства
internal class RoadDeviceBuilder : RoadDevice
{
    public RoadDeviceBuilder() : base()
    {

    }

    public RoadDeviceBuilder WithIdAndName(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public RoadDeviceBuilder WithIsDecomissionedFlag(bool isDecommissioned)
    {
        this.IsDecommissioned = isDecommissioned;
        return this;
    }

    public RoadDevice Build()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```