# Как правильно передавать объекты из Entity Framework во View в WPF с использованием MVVM?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Насколько мне известно, классы объектов, которые привязываются к контролам во View, должны реализовывать интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged. Допустим, я получаю из репозитория коллекцию сущностей EF. По всей видимости, передавать эту коллекцию напрямую во View - неправильно. Следовательно, нужно во ViewModel создать "обёртку" для этой коллекции? Использовать new ObservebleCollection()?
Как сделать это грамотно?

Comment: Это достаточно обширный вопрос. Посмотрите [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/379255/10105) (предупреждаю, много текста).

Comment: _"получаю из репозитория коллекцию сущностей EF."_ -- на уровне кода есть классы. и есть экземпляры, которые создаются в DbContext и в эти объекты записываются данные полученные из бд. но вы можете сами создать в своем коде создать и заполнить эти объекты. т.е. нет каких-то особых "сущностей EF".

Comment: @Stack, https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb387161(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @klutch1991 +1, но у вас Code First? и там сказано: "задавая в коде определения классов". т.е. в коде есть классы, а DbContext занимается десериализаций данных, полученных из базы. представьте, что его нет и вы создаете объекты вручную. как их передавать "во View" - известно. через DataContext. точно также можно передать объекты, которые были созданы в DbContext.

Comment: @Stack, да, я использую Code First. Вопрос заключается скорее в том, как преобразовать объекты модели EDM в объекты модели паттерна MVVM.

Comment: @klutch1991 _"как преобразовать объекты модели"_ -- объекты, полученные через DbContext, можно просто передать в DataContext. Но если надо соблюдать MVVM, то объекты надо обернуть в объекты ViewModel.

Comment: @klutch1991 если надо сделать много оберток, то см. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484929/196972

Comment: @Stack, А как быть, если мне нужно, скажем, передать на вьюшку целую коллекцию объектов, которые нужно отобразить в ListView, или в DataGrid?

Comment: @klutch1991  _"передать на вьюшку целую коллекцию объектов,"_ -- так же как и обычный объект. просто в xaml будет привязка к элементам коллекции, и потом к свойствам элемента/объекта.