# C# , WinForms , обработка кода который сохранен в виде текста

Tags: c#, winforms

Хотелось бы узнать есть ли в C# такая возможность:
есть код сохраненный в виде текста.

например,

```
string textProg=" int a=5; int b=3; int c=a*b;"
```

возможно, ли заставить его заработать.  Спасибо!!!

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под _заставить его заработать_?

Comment: @Grundy сделать его чёрным

Comment: вот тут уже отвечали на похожий вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/477348/198316

Answer (score 0):

Да, воспользуйтесь расширением CSharpCodeProvider

```
StringBuilder code = new StringBuilder();
code.AppendLine("using System;");
...(Класс и т.п.)
code.AppendLine(" int a=5; int b=3; int c=a*b;");

CSharpCodeProvider compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();

... (ваши настройки)
```

Comment: а как оно(_ReflectionEmitLanguage_) тут может помочь?

Comment: что должно находиться на месте `...`?

Answer (score 0):

Подключить пакет [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting/) через Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting
```

И можно выполнять код на лету:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string textProg = "int a=5; int b=3; int c=a*b;";

            textProg += "return c;";

            var result = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<int>(textProg).Result;

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а у него есть ограничения на то, какие конструкции можно использовать?

Comment: @Grundy явного - нет. неявное можно сделать через [создание отдельного compilation](http://www.filipekberg.se/2011/12/08/hosted-execution-of-smaller-code-snippets-with-roslyn/) с полным контролем надо допустимыми конструкциями и типами.