# Компиляция файла в коде

Tags: c#, компиляция

Как можно скомпилировать .cs файл в коде?
Не используя командную строку.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/304655

Comment: @Qwertiy: Думаю, стоит оформить в виде ответа.

Comment: @VladD, согласен, но времени не было написать.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477348/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4/490883#490883

Answer (score 2):

Нужно воспользоваться классом `CSharpCodeProvider`, а также типами из пространства имен `System.CodeDom.Compiler`:

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

...

// компилятор
var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
ICodeCompiler compiler = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();

// параметры компиляции
var parameters = new CompilerParameters()
{
    // указываем, что генерируем исполняемый файл (exe)
    GenerateExecutable = true,
    // если хотим сохранить на диск
    OutputAssembly = "...",
    // если хотим сохранить в памяти
    // (хотя файл все равно cгенерируется во временной директории)
    //GenerateInMemory = true
};

// компилируем
var source = File.ReadAll("SomeFile.cs");
CompilerResults results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, source);

// проверяем, есть ли ошибки
if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Line number {error.Line}, error number {error.ErrorNumber}: {error.ErrorText}");
    }
}

// если нужно обратиться к скомпилированной сборке,
// используйте свойство results.CompiledAssembly
```

Answer (score 0):

Очень удобно использовать Roslyn https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Примеры можно посмотреть здесь 
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples#exprstrong

и здесь

[Как программно откомпилировать класс и вызвать его метод?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477348/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4/490883#490883)