# C# динамическое компилирование

Tags: c#

Всем привет.

У меня есть код, который компилирует на run time маленький кусочек другого кода

```
eq = "namespace test { 
    public class Test {
      public string Upper(string lower, string lower2) { 
         return lower.ToUpper() + lower2.ToUpper(); } } }";
```

Но когда я его немного усложняю,

```
eq = "namespace test { 
   public class Test{
     public int Itest(int str){
        MathFun mf = new MathFun();
        int result = mf.calcul(str);
        return result;}}}";
```

компилятор выдает ошибку.

Могу добавить, что класс `MathFun` в том же `project` где и `main()`, а его `namespace` — `test`.

Подскажите, как я могу компилировать мою «программку», где создаётся объект.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477348/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/309340/

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/309850/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если для компиляции используется CodeDom (`CSharpCodeProvider`), то необходимо добавить в параметры компилятора ссылку на сборку, где находится тип `MathFun`. Путь к ней можно получить через `typeof(MathFun).Assembly.Location`:

```
namespace test
{
    // класс, к которому нужно получить доступ в генерируемой сборке
    public class MathFun
    {
        // в качестве примера метод просто возвращает свой аргумент
        public int calcul(int str)
        {
            return str;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var eq = @"namespace test { 
   public class Test{
     public int Itest(int str){
        MathFun mf = new MathFun();
        int result = mf.calcul(str);
        return result;}}}";

            var prms = new CompilerParameters();
            prms.GenerateInMemory = true;
            prms.GenerateExecutable = false;

            // добавляем референс на сборку с типом MathFun
            prms.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof(MathFun).Assembly.Location);

            var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            var compileResult = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(prms, eq);

            // тест созданной сборки, создание экземпляра класса Test и вызов метода Itest
            var typeTest = compileResult.CompiledAssembly.GetType("test.Test");
            var itestMethod = typeTest.GetMethod("Itest");
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeTest);

            var result = itestMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] { 42 });
            Console.WriteLine(result); // выводит 42
        }
    }
}
```

---

Если же используется Roslyn, то аналогичную ссылку нужно добавить в массив объектов `MetadataReference`:

```
var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(eq);
var options = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary);
var refs = new[] {
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(MathFun).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)
};

var compiler = CSharpCompilation.Create(
        "testasm", new[] { syntaxTree }, refs, options);

Assembly asm;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
    compiler.Emit(stream);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    asm = Assembly.Load(stream.ToArray());
}

var typeTest = asm.GetType("test.Test");

// ...
```

---

Ошибки компиляции можно вывести в консоль:

```
// ...
var compileResult = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(prms, eq);

if (compileResult.Errors.HasErrors) {
    foreach (var error in compileResult.Errors) {
        Console.WriteLine(error);
    }
}
```

В вашем случае нужно проверить две вещи:

- В компилируемом коде добавлены строки

  ```
  using OpenQA.Selenium;
  using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
  ```
- Добавлены ссылки на `WebDriver.dll` и `System.dll`.

Вот такой код работает:

```
var eq =
@"using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
namespace test {
    class Test {
        public void m()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(""http://www.google.com"");
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name(""q""));
            element.SendKeys(""executeautomation"");
        }
    }
}";

var prms = new CompilerParameters();
prms.GenerateInMemory = true;
prms.GenerateExecutable = false;

// ссылка на WebDriver.dll (либо строкой прописать полный путь до этой сборки)
prms.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof(OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver).Assembly.Location);
// ссылка на System.dll
prms.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");

var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var compileResult = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(prms, eq);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, все работает. 
Но теперь у меня проблема с подключением библиотеки (Selenium.dll). 
Я пытаюсь динамически компилировать данный код :
`IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
     driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
     IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
     element.SendKeys("executeautomation");
     driver.Close();` 
P.S. я использовала код из первого примера

Comment: @IrynaBatychka обновил ответ